# Show Division dependent upon form choice

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form which I am working on that has 3 choices of brand as the first selection, I need to show 1 of 3 divisions dependent upon which choice has been selected.

Is this possible using jQuery? If so what function should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a example for you http://jsfiddle.net/rtXLe/

```
<select>
    <option value="#divA">a</option>
    <option value="#divB">b</option>
</select>

<div id="divA" class="brandDiv">brand A</div>
<div id="divB" class="brandDiv">brand B</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("select").change(function() {
            // hide all brands first
            $("div.brandDiv").hide();
            // val is something like #div1 or #div2
            var targetId = $(this).val();
            // show the new selected one
            $(targetId).show();
        });
    });         
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing your HTML, but the chances are you're going to want to bind a [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler to the element that controls this selection. For example:

```
$("#someSelect").change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    //Do something based on the selected value
});
```

Aside from that, you'll probably want to look at the [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods. Post your markup and it will be far easier to help!

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery.change event will help you build a handler based on a select field or radio button group that has been "changed". From there you can show the div needed.

More documentation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery methods [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) will get you far on your way. You would use `.change()` to register an event handler for the `change` event of the 
 input and the other two to perform the style manipulation in that handler.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a look at http://api.jquery.com/bind/ which lets you bind all kinds of dom events to functions. There are also shortcuts to bind, the one you should use here is .change http://api.jquery.com/change/

You should make a connection between the  value attribute of of the option tag and the class of the div to be shown/hidden. (You can use .show/.hide from jQuery).

Also take care what happens when you reload the page, either set the selected atribute of the option tag via a backend language or check the value set when the DOM is loaded ($(document).ready).

So basicly run a check on domready (what value is selected, hide all divs, show the right one)
and then bind the onchange event to more or less the same thing.

Best,